# Add a specific IAM role to the ECS task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS task running a container that requires permissions from resources, that are all a part of a specific IAM role. I am trying to add that specific role to the task definition on the console, but the only role I see is the auto-generated one by ECS.

I don't see all the IAM role in the dropdown. How do I access them?
[image]

Comment: I tried typing the complete name of the role in the search text field of the dropdown, but nothing shows up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a new role make sure you choose elastic container service task

[image]

Or

If you can edit the existing role, enter the trusted entity, and edit with the following

[image]

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to edit the existing roles to be of this type i.e ECS task under use case? Because my code looks for a specific role name, and I don't want to make changes to the code, instead I just want to make the existing role eligible for ecs

Comment: Yes, you can edit the existing role, enter the trusted entity, and edit with the following:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}